# Is this "Only" checkbox option a default MUI component?

Tags: checkboxes, material-design

I saw this option when I was using Google Flights. It's pretty handy if there's a long list of options and you only want to select one.

Does anyone know if this is a default MUI component? I can't find it on MUI's documentation, but wanted to make sure I didn't miss it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a default component. Technically it acts as a radio button, so selecting it will deselect all options (which are checkboxes by default).

You're right this is an excellent feature and while it only works on desktop, it's really helpful. But going back to your question, it's not a default component, it's achieved with Javascript and CSS.